# Gitlab failing at sending emails

Tags: email, smtp, gitlab, mail-server

I have the following configuration set up in my /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'testing@mydom.com'
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = 'secure.emailsrvr.com'
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = 'testing@mydom.com'
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = 'password'
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = 'mydom.info'
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = 'login'
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
```

Note: I have tried setting smtp_domain to mydom.com just in case but still no change.

Under sidekiq in the admin panel I get the following errors:

```
Worker: Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer
Arguments:"---\n- !ruby/class 'Notify'\n- :project_access_granted_email\n- - 68\n"
Error: ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)

Worker: Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer
Arguments: "---\n- !ruby/class 'Notify'\n- :group_access_granted_email\n- - 32\n"
Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find UsersGroup with 'id'=32
```

This is the equivalent content in /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/environments/production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address => 'secure.emailsrvr.com',
   :port => 465,
   :domain => 'mydom.info',
   :authentication => :login,
   :user_name => 'testing@mydom.com',
   :password => 'password',
   :enable_starttls_auto => true,
   :tls => true
  }
```

Edit
Is there anything at least I can use to test that these configurations are correct?

Comment: are you sure its not an internet problem ? maybe the internet is slow and that's the reason for the connection timeout

Comment: I don't have any issues with internet that I can noice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with incorrect Configuration details.

Comment: Can you maybe edit this post and enter the correct values, marking it also as the right answer? It could help others with same problems.

Comment: The details such as address and credentials where the issue in my case. not the configuration per-se.